# Is it possible to enroll in the Developer Program for multiple organisations with a single Apple ID?

Tags: developer-program

I do some simple app management for a couple of not-for-profits and charities. They don't have much of an IT setup with business emails so I use my personal email and Apple ID.

My Apple ID is the Account Holder for one organisation developer account and I want to add another (i.e. the organisation doesn't yet have an Apple Developer account and I will enrol for them). When I click enroll at https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/, I'm met with this message:

---

## Sorry, you can’t enroll at this time.

Your Apple ID is already associated with the Account Holder of a membership.

---

I just want to confirm that I would have to create a new Apple ID for each organisation that I want to create an Apple Developer account for. Or is there another way that doesn't require me to manage multiple Apple IDs?

Comment: Are you planning on individual memberships for each organization or organizational accounts? Why do they need their own Developer account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Apple ID can participate as a developer and [many other roles in multiple organizations](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/).

Multiple organizations can not have the same primary Apple ID.

This is by design for only the account holder role and unlikely to change IMO.